# How to find out which package is really required?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

As an example, current case -- I try to install GlassFish adapter in Eclipse. It fails, because it requires "org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web 0.0.0".

How can I figure out from the class (?) name which package I have to install? When I select Eclipse repository and search for "jst" I got 3 hits (from memory: JST Server Adapters, JST Server Adapters Extensions, and JST Server UI -- all 3 are now installed, and the requirement is still not met).

**Please note, this is just example** -- the question is not how to install GF, but how decode class (?) name into package.

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler, updated.

Comment: Developing with Java EE requires "Eclipse for Java EE", not "Eclipse for Java".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dependency isn't automatically determined, then I end up searching Google for the required dependencies of the plugin. Another way is to search for the class name and determining what Eclipse package that class is in. I really don't think there is any better way, other then guessing.

---

For example, I entered `org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web` into Google and ended at the [WPT](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) project page. Clicking around there I ended up the [Java EE Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jee/) page, and then the [component overview](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/j2ee/api/j2ee_componentoverview.html) page, which ultimately shows the package in question. I would then suspect that "Java EE Tools" is the Eclipse plugin that needs to be installed because of this text:

> The Java EE project is comprised of jst.common , jst.j2ee , jst.servlet , jst.ejb , and jst.web subprojects. The following diagram visualizes the dependencies among these components, and the relevant WST subcomponent dependencies.

However, it appears Eclipse itself calls this "Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools" instead.

It's a headache, I am not going to argue that.

Comment: I already googled, but how do I do the second option you describe? Take for example the class I wrote about.

Comment: Ok, I think I have to drink something stronger, because I already have WPT installed :-) so now I feel a little dizzy.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you can use [Jarfinder](http://www.jarfinder.com/). This service lets you type a class name and find which JAR contain it. You can also search JAR by names

[This is the result](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/search/~org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web~) for your query `org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web*`

Comment: Thank you but I don't see how this solve the issue. The link you provided is for searching classes, this one I know, when I switch to searching a jar, nothing is found. So I didn't move an inch.

Comment: What? When you click a class name, it takes you to a download page, for example [SecurityConstraint](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.webapplication.SecurityConstraint). Moreover, once you know the JAR name, you can easily google for it and find the project's home